# Eclipse Maven - Auto Increment pom version before committing to GitHub?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I am looking for a solution to this. Here is my setup:

Local Eclipse with all maven projects on. When i commit them to GitHub, my Jenkins server automatically builds the project. (For every push to github)

However, in my Maven repository on the Jenkins server, i want to be able to get each one (1.0.1 -> 1.0.2 etc.) is there any way i can do this? Ideally an eclipse plugin so that it changes the version before it gets to GitHub.

If i used the maven-version-plugin, it would not update on my local eclipse machine, therefore it would just use the same version each time.

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the maven-release-plugin which exactly does things like this. This comprises of two steps. First mvn [release:prepare](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) and second mvn [release:perform](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html).

Comment: I need it to incremtent the version before it goes to github, it cant be done with maven because jenkins (which runs the maven build) gets the source when github is updated.

Comment: You didn't understand the intention of the maven-release-plugin. If you run a release build it will checkout the sources and run a release.prepare on it which changes the version, changes the pom's, creates the tag etc. and pushed back to github. I don't see your problem.

Comment: but if it pushes it back to github, Jenkins would build it again because the source has changed, causing an infinite loop

Comment: You should let your Jenkins do the release build.

Comment: What do you mean? Jenkins is the builder for the jar?